# Will .NET 4.0 apps work on Win 2008 R2 Server Core?

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2, server-core

When Windows Server 2008 R2 was launched, the "server core" edition started to become useful to me, because it lets me deploy .NET background applications isolated on their own virtual machine instance with only a small fraction of all the disk space overhead of a default Windows Server installation, and very few Windows Updates. It comes with a subset of .NET 3.5 SP1 integrated (as an optional feature).

Now that .NET 4.0 is released, the redistributables explicitly state that it's not support on Server Core. Any chance that there will be a separate download available for Server Core (e. g. without WPF) any time soon, has anybody heard about it?

Comment: Might be worth posting here : http://serverfault.com

Comment: You're probably right, however right know in this week probably mostly developers have to answer the question - "switch to .net 4.0 now or later?" - most admins will notice the problem at least one development iteration later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything I have read says no. I would imagine that this will change but unfortunately it doesn't look like it will be soon.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to here, but the only answer ;-) Thanks.

Comment: I know, sorry. Although given that they are trying to split the framework into distinct parts so you only download what you need you may find you get 4.0 quicker that you think.

Answer (score 3):

Since 2011-02-21, it is possible to run .NET 4.0 apps on Windows 2008 R2 Server Core.  To enable .NET 4.0 support, you need to install [Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c3202ce6-4056-4059-8a1b-3a9b77cdfdda&displaylang=en) and the [.NET 4.0 Standalone Installer for Server Core](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=211830).